# pip install -e successful, import fails: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, openai-gym

I'm trying to install a module I'm developing. When I use 'pip install -e .', it outputs 'Successfully installed gym-mabifish' but when I try to import the module using 'import gym_mabifish' I'm getting 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "gym_mabifish"'.

Here's the structure of the package:

```
gym-mabifish/
     setup.py ( https://pastebin.com/1wNykyKw )
     gym_mabifish/
          __init__.py ( https://pastebin.com/GtQid3Nk )
          envs/
               __init__.py ( https://pastebin.com/Txfk0ezE )
               mabifish_env.py ( https://pastebin.com/g50zBbus )
```

I'm using the random_agent from OpenAI gym to test it. ( https://pastebin.com/72LETtxd )

The package is shown in pip list:

```
gym-mabifish (0.0.1, x:\path\to\project\gym-mabifish)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `pip` and your `python` are both from the same Python version? For example, one common thing macOS users run into is that they install a second Python, which is lower on the PATH than the pre-installed Apple Python, so `python` runs Apple's Python, but Apple's Python doesn't come with pip, so `pip` installs packages for the other Python.

Comment: Instead of using 'pip install' I used 'python -m pip install' and it seems to be working. You want to copy your comment into an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you have two (or more) Python installations, and your `pip` and `python` come from different installations.

Ideally, you want to solve that problem. But in some cases, it's very difficult. On Windows, managing the PATH can be a nightmare. On macOS, if you install a second Python 2.7 alongside the Apple pre-installed Python 2.7 (which doesn't come with `pip`), things get confusing.

So, the officially recommended solution nowadays is to just [use the `-m` flag to run pip using whichever command you normally use to run Python](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage).

Everything below is as of early 2018. It's changed a few times in the past few years, and may well change again in the future, so it's always best to go right to [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) in the docs, or the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/). But as a summary:

Ideally you're using a virtual environment, in which case this is just `python`. But if not:

- [Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/):

  - `py`
- [*nix](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/):

  - `python` only if you're explicitly using whatever came with your OS/distro as a default.
  - `python3` if you're using 3.x on *nix](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)
  - `python2.7` if you're using Apple's default Python 2.7 on macOS.
  - `python2` if you're using any other 2.x on *nix.

So, for example, on Windows, it should be:

```
py -m pip install gym-mabifish
```

… and then when you run your script like this:

```
py myscript.py
```

… it will be able to `import gym_mabifish`.