# maintaining multiple python versions in anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have anaconda installed on my windows pc that have 3.6 version of python and beside that I also have python 2.7.14 installed. I had renamed anaconda's python as python 3, so that I can access both the versions of python, but I am unable to use the pip of both.

Whenever I write `pip --version` on command prompt, I access pip version of python 2.7.14. How to access pip of python present in anaconda folder? In windows power shell python's 3.6 version is accessed by writing .\python 3 so how to access pip of python's 3.6 version in command prompt as well as windows power shell?

Comment: So what you want, is to set the default pip to pip3 correct? If that is the case you can try to use alias. Here is how you would do it, alias='path to pip3'. Or you could simply type pip3 if you want the pip version of python 3.6

Comment: The best answer is to not use the `pip` script, but instead run it as a module: `python3 -m pip install whatever` and `python2 -m pip install whatever`. Or, even better, use the `py` launcher for running both Python and pip.

Comment: See [this answer I just wrote for a related but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615201/pip-install-e-successful-import-fails-modulenotfounderror/50615402#50615402) for more details.